# Same db table for two models

Tags: javascript, node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

Is it possible to have to models (client, vendor) for one database table?
I made a **partner** model, which uses partner table. My **client** and **vendor** models inherit from partner model.

```
http://localhost:3000/api/partners
```

gives back all the data from the db table, but

```
http://localhost:3000/api/vendors
```

does not have any result.

vendors and clients are almost identical, only their types and two other properties are different. I want to have all the records from the table `partner` with type 'vendor' from the endpoint

```
http://localhost:3000/api/vendors
```

and all the partners with type `client` from

```
http://localhost:3000/api/clients
```

(`http://localhost:3000/api/partners` should be hidden)

**EDIT**
**models/vendor.js**

```
{
  "name": "vendor",
  "base": "partner",
  "strict": false,
  "idInjection": false,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true,
    "postgresql": {
      "table": "partner"
    }    
  },
...
}
```

after reboot my server I am still getting:

```
{
  "links": {
    "self": "http://localhost:3000/api/vendors"
  },
  "data": []
}
```

In explorer I can see the properties of `partner` on `vendor`'s *Model Schema*

Comment: In your vendor.json file, did you try to add "schema" property to postgresql? I think with its should be "strongloop" as described here: https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/PostgreSQL+connector#PostgreSQLconnector-Definingmodels

Comment: @ReuvenChacha yes I added, but no luck. (I even tried "schema": "public" )

Comment: @ReuvenChacha yes I added, but no luck. I added "schema": "public" to both models (partner and vendor). With "schema": "strongloop" it did not work for partner. => no table strongloop.partner

Comment: ok, anyway I'm working with the exact same approach using mongodb and for me it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep. You just need to update the [options on the models' config files](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Model+definition+JSON+file#ModeldefinitionJSONfile-Datasource-specificoptions) to point to a specific table. Make sure you only identify properties in each model that pertain to that model (and not the other one) and then you can manually [inject the `type` before saving](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Operation+hooks#Operationhooks-beforesave):

In `common/models/partner.json` AND `common/models/vendor.json`:

```
...
  "options": {
    "mysql": {
      "table": "partner"
    }
  }
...
```

Then add a `before save` hook to each model's JS file (`common/models/vendor.js`):

```
module.exports = function(Vendor) {
  Vendor.observe('before save', function(ctx, next) {
    ctx.instance.type = 'vendor';
    next();
  });
};
```

Comment: thanks. Actually I have already tired your suggestion, but did not work, see my update on OP.

Comment: I looked at your comment, but it seems like it _did_ work in that both models access the same table, but that they both show the same properties, is that correct? If so, then make sure you are specifying the `properties` correctly and that you set the `strict` option.

Comment: it was a stupid mistake: I forgot to set vendor's Data source to postgre

Comment: Ah!! Well, glad you got that sorted. Good luck!